# Automatic bill generator

Tags: android, image-scanner

I want to create an mobile application that has a reader to scan small stickers with numbers and name on it . The scanner is connected to the phone and the user scans the sticker for any number of items and the bill is generated . I couldnt find any help on the internet . How to proceed in making this app ?

Comment: You want to scan over reader device or camera phone?

Comment: I want to scan from reader device which is from usb . Usb device connects with the app on the mobile

Comment: It will a bit difficult. You have to check your reader device's sdk for something to communicate from it to device. Without it, you cannot do anything.

Comment: What if I want to use the camera phone

Comment: So you need a OCR library which help you detect text and number on the sticker and you will use them to generate bill. You can check this first. https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two